# Загрузка файлов Asp.net

Tags: c#, база-данных, asp.net-mvc, upload

Мне нужно реализовать загрузку файлов на сервер и сохранения пути до них в бд. Проблема в том, что у меня много таблиц (около 30) в которые может быть сохранён путь, и если использовать единственную хранимую процедуру, то получится большое количество **if**-ов. Поэтому я решил написать много хранимок и вызывать конкретно нужную, благодаря этому мне удалось использовать место ≈90 проверок всего лишь ≈30 (при загрузки 3 файлов в худшем случаи, когда последний if) Темнеменее мне кажется, что это какой-то велосипед и скорее всего есть какие-то лучшие способы это сделать, к тому же мне не нравится повторяющийся код во втором методе. Как можно лучше решить ряд этих проблем?

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UploadAjax(string nameJournal)
    {
        int count = -1;
        string[] files = new string[Request.Files.Count];
        string relativePath = "~/Files/nameJournal/" + id;
        var absolutePath = Server.MapPath(relativePath);
        string resultError = "Файлы не загружены:";
        if (!Directory.Exists(absolutePath))
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = Directory.CreateDirectory(absolutePath);
        }
        foreach (string fileNameFromView in Request.Files)
        {
            count += 1;
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileNameFromView];
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName) + "_"
                + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
                + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            try
            {
                    file.SaveAs(absolutePath + "/" + fileName);
                    files[count] = file.FileName;             
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                resultError += string.Format("\n{0}", file.FileName);
            }

        }
        return Json(UploadDataBase(files, resultError, relativePath, string nameJournal));
    }
```

И второй метод

```
        public string UploadDataBase(string[] files, string resultError, string relativePath, nameJournal)
        {
            string resultSuccess = "Файлы загружены:";
            if (nameJournal == "ТАКОМУ-ТО")
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (files[i] != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            //Хранимка1
                           resultSuccess += string.Format("\n{0}", files[i]);
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(relativePath + "/" + files[i]));
                            resultError += string.Format("\n{0}", files[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }  
else if (nameJournal == "ТАКОМУ-ТО2")
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (files[i] != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            //Хранимка2
                           resultSuccess += string.Format("\n{0}", files[i]);
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(relativePath + "/" + files[i]));
                            resultError += string.Format("\n{0}", files[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }                        
            return resultSuccess + "\n\n" + resultError;
        }
```

Comment: Может вам лучше создать таблицу в которой вы будите хранить все пути, а так же ссылку на сущность которой принадлежит путь?

Answer (score 1):

Если код в IF всегда одинаковый, почему бы не заменить IFы на Dictionary?

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"JournalID1","StoredProcID1"},
    {"JournalID2","StoredProcID2"},
}

public string UploadDataBase(string[] files, string resultError, string relativePath, string nameJournal)
{
    string resultSuccess = "Файлы загружены:";
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(nameJournal))
    {
        var proc = dictionary[nameJournal];

        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            if (files[i] != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Хранимка1
                    // use proc here
                    resultSuccess += string.Format("\n{0}", files[i]);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(relativePath + "/" + files[i]));
                    resultError += string.Format("\n{0}", files[i]);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        // Эррор, журнал не найден
    }
    return resultSuccess + "\n\n" + resultError;
}
```