# Как сделать локальное хранилище фотографий без использования SQL? (ASP.Net MCV5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать хранение личных фотографий пользователей и отображение в профиле (разрабатываю фотогалерею пользователей ASP.Net MCV5 Windows c авторизацией). У меня проект MVC с проверкой подлинности Windows (Active Directory), получаю данные из AD (ФИО, Должность и т.д.):

```
public class Person
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Office { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string ExtensionPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentNumber { get; set; }
    public string Subdivision { get; set; }
    public string Manager { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDay { get; set; }
    public string sAMAccountName { get; set; }


}
```

Получаю текущего авторизованного пользователя через `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`.

Создаю ещё одну модель `PersonImage`:

```
public class PersonImage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FaleName { get; set; } // название картинки     
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string AdLoginName { get; set; }//ну или хранить DisplayName 
}
```

Может кто сталкивался с такой задачей. Пытаюсь реализовать файловое хранилище, без использования SQL.

Comment: Не любите sql - посмотрите в сторону MongoDB.

Comment: @aepot, дело не в SQL. Просто данные из AD пишутся не в базу, чтоб делать связи. Можно же как то организовать файловое хранилище....

Comment: А предыдущие вопросы, где вам объяснили подробно вы решилил удалить? Ну такое. В PersonImage замените Name на FileName. Можете создать в AD кастомный атрибут для пользователя и в нём хранить. С моей точки зрения дико не использовать базу данных, я думаю, когда вы профессионально вырастете - будете с улыбкой вспоминать этот проект.

Comment: @AK, хранить в атрибутах AD фотографию не думаю хорошим вариантом

Comment: Простите, а тогда где? В капусте? В банке из-под огурцов? Вы не хотите в базе данных SQL, вы не хотите в базе mongoDB, окей, вам перебрать все базы и вы от всего отказываетесь. Даже AD/LDAP является базой данных, пусть и специфической, но я вам перечислил реальный сценарий как её используют в корпоративной среде. Но вам не подходит. Это не вопрос. Вопрос это "хочу так, как сделать?" А у вас хочу то, не знаю что. Проголосовал за закрытие. Разберитесь с ТЗ, потом реализуйте. Пока у вас стыдобища выходит, за которую перед коллегами стыдно.

Comment: @AK, хранить в атрибутах AD фотографию не думаю хорошим вариантом. 1 Могут появится глюки в работе самой AD. 2) Возможно хранить только 1 фото и 1 аватар. Но если речь пойдет о галерее? Хорошо, Вы меня убедили)) перейти  к использованию SQL. Может подтолкнете в направление сделать соотношения модели пользователя и картинки(фотографии) если я не пишу пользователей в базу?

Comment: Первое. Вам предложили хранить не фото в AD, а имена файлов, которые искать на диске. Про кастомный атрибуты в AD - это реальный кейс, у меня админы так ОДНУ фото сотрудника для outlook хранят. Второе. Вы даже не понимаете, как тормозит диск, когда на нём хранится много файлов в одной папке - а я уже вижу стопку костылей, которые придётся подкладывать и в каких местах. Но если вы так хотите файлы? Господи, да ради бога! Просто я не понимаю что вы спрашиваете: ну сохраняйте файлы, а потом читайте файлы, в чём вопрос? Так тоже можно реализовать, но в чём конкретный вопрос?

Comment: По поводу SQL я вас уже подталкивал в прошлом вопросе, вам в комментариях были подробно описаны связки как работает negotiate - я не поленился и из реального проекта всё выписал. Грохнули - ну сами себе злобный буратино, мне лень заново тратить время. В модель PersonImage добавили бы string AdLoginName и делов.

Comment: @AK, Вопрос конкретно в том как и реализовать для пользователя личную галерею фотографий. Примерно я понял что вы предлагаете, хранить фотографии на диске, а ссылки на фотографии в БД. Идентификатором в БД использовать логин авторизованного пользователя, и делать выборку? Правильно ли я понял?

Comment: Правильно. На словах звучит правильно. Можете также привести в поле ответ класс модели, чтобы убедиться, что и код не расходится со словами.

Comment: @AK
`public class PersonImage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FaleName { get; set; } // название картинки
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string AdLoginName { get; set; }//ну или хранить DisplayName
}
`

Comment: Скажите, а вы знаете, что программист пишет код только 10% рабочего времени, а в основном читает? Я не хочу читать код из комментариев с вырвиглазным форматированием (его нет в комментариях, только в вопросах и ответах), глаза сломать можно.

Comment: Под постом с вопросом есть кнопка "Править"

Comment: @aepot, спасибо)

Comment: @AK, принял, исправлюсь)

Comment: Посмотрел обновлённый вопрос. Да, структура вполне реализуемый вариант. Хранить в AdLoginName надо именно HttpContext.User.Identity.Name - там будет строка вида domain\username, вам вполне подойдёт и она уникальна в домене в отличие от DisplayName (например, у меня в организации работает около тридцати однофамильцев, восемь полных тёзок). Если картинок у одного пользователя будет более тысячи - рекомендую сразу в дополнение к FileName хранить и каталог, делать древовидную структуру: при более 1000 файлах в папке начинаются тормоза, что под виндой, что под линуксом.

Comment: @AK, Спасибо за совет. А не могли бы направить (ссылку на ресурс или еще как ни будь) в описании логики для контроллера для загрузки и отображении картинок?

Comment: @AK, А так большое Вам спасибо за помощь. Много дельных советов дали)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/975828/213987 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/830627/213987 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/830433/213987 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/711311/213987 https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/24.6.php https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/21.3.php и т.п.